# Terminal - Weird spaces included when typing fast

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, command-line

Whenever I want to use the pipe operator in the terminal, I get a weird kind of "bug":

[image: The "bug" in the terminal]

As is shown in the image above, I can type the exact same command twice and it will sometimes register it or sometimes include some spacing in the command, as can be seen in the error message. The only difference between the two commands was the speed I typed them, with fast typing the char sequence "| " (without the "") leading to the error.
I've checked in the terminal settings if this sequence somehow triggers a shortcut, but I did not find anything.

In case it matters, I'm using a swiss keyboard. The layout is as follows:

[image: Swiss keyboard layout for OS X]

To produce the "|" character, I press "alt + 7". Does anybody know what the cause of this problem is?

Comment: Please add the system version and the keyboard/Mac model (e.g. 10.11.4 & Magic Keyboard)!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You aren't releasing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key (aka <kbd>Option</kbd>) quickly enough after typing the "|", so you're getting <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>, which is a non-breaking space. This looks like a normal space but gets treated as part of the command name rather than as a separator. See [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/78245/how-to-disable-the-option-space-key-combination-for-non-breaking-spaces) for some options to disable the <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> key combo.